# Upgrade python from 3.8.5 to 3.8.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: linux, upgrade, python3

I'm currently trying to upgrade the python version from 3.8.5 to 3.8.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I've been able to find information to upgrade python version from version `X.Y1` to `X.Y2` (minor release in semantic version),
but not to upgrade version from `X.Y.Z1` to `X.Y.Z2` (patch level in semantic version).

I've tried (without success) the recommendations listed in:

- [Updating Python on Ubuntu system](https://superuser.com/questions/241865/updating-python-on-ubuntu-system)
- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I'm also planning to migrate my project to 3.9.6 in July and I would like to have a robust and simple method to upgrade the version with the next python 3.9 patches .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `apt show python3.8` output, there are only 2 versions of the official `python3.8` package available as of this writing, `3.8.2` and `3.8.5` (barring different package releases for the same Python version).

If you need another version, you need to add another Python installation independent from the distro's one.

I'd recommend [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for that. It allows to install any number of alternative Python versions and switch between them. Check out its README (on the same page) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that just a selective number of python versions where added to apt registry. But, that totally make sense considering the interaction of python why the rest of the os